# Two UIbutton with different width after autoresizing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I have two UI buttons placed equal horrizontally, i have tried many autolayouts, but i could not make it both of equal heights and within screen limits. i can make it of same width but then the second button goes out of screen. Screen shot is attached as well.
Can you please guide me how can i do this?[image: Screen shot for two buttons]

Comment: Have you tried setting constraints manually within interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: with interface builder (by myself).

Comment: Did you select the pin menu and then constrain the width and height of the `UIButton`s?

Comment: Please attach screenshot of your constraints added via IB